# Drupal 6 increase user login time

Tags: drupal, authentication

How can I increase time for keeping user logged in.

Even after comming back after few days.

I don't want users to login each time they open a browser.

Comment: why do I have to use some fajncy persisten login module ??
I want to do it by changing settings.

Comment: Modules and their broad sweep of functionality and developer effort is half the reason to use Drupal.

Comment: I added an answer to your other question regarding this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613303/drupal-persistent-login-why-use/1618005#1618005), with the main point being that you can increase the login time for users without the need for additional modules by adjusting some entries in settings.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here:

http://drupalmodules.com/module/persistent-login

or search for persistent login or login cookie in the drupal modules site.